# Network error IOException: Connection refused (Android)

Tags: android, networking, jdbc, tcp, jtds

I'm trying to connect my android to my sql server (using jtds driver) through the port 1433, which I have already set under TCP/IP IPALL port in Sql server configuration manager.

Here are some images to show the configuration: [IP address of SQl server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RXSQI.jpg), [IPALL Tcp/ip port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dzc9B.jpg)

I've also enabled TCP/IP itself, but I'm getting this error:

> Network error IOException: Connection refused

I've tried many different connection strings below but I still keep getting the same error:

```
string db, un, pass;
un ="abby";
pass = "123";

   // db = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DESKTOP-UXE5RL\\SQLENT2016";
   // db = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DESKTOP-UXE5RL:3225/SQLENT2016;DatabaseName=FlowerDB";
   // db = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DESKTOP-UXE5RL\\SQLENT2016";
   // db = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://DESKTOP-UXE5RL\\SQLENT2016:3225/FlowerDB";
   // db = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.2/FlowerDB;instance=SQLENT2016";
    // db = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.2/FlowerDB;instance=SQLENT2016";
   // db = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.2\\SQLENT2016:1433;databaseName=FlowerDB";
    db = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://192.168.1.2:1433;databaseName=FlowerDB;instance=SQLENT2016;user=abby;password=123";


// con = DriverManager.getConnection(db, un, pass);
con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
```

Please advise me thanks!

Comment: The server isn't running at that IP:port, or at all.

Comment: @EJP Can u tell me how to find the correct IP:port?

Comment: Check the server configuration?

Comment: On the sql server machine execute netstat command or similar to check that SQL server is actually listening on all interfaces (IP addresses) and port 1433. It may happen that SQL server is listening on localhost only, other port or not running.